# Azure Functions Queue empty

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-queues

I am new to Azure. Forgive me if the question is basic.
I have the following http trigger intended to stream messages to the Queue Storage.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, msg: func.Out[func.QueueMessage]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    input_msg = req.params.get('message')
    logging.info(input_msg)
    msg.set(input_msg)

    return func.HttpResponse(status_code=200, body='GotIt')
```

Tested it Locally and;
[image]

Deployed it and it runs ok as well
[image]

However, when I check the queue it is empty;

[image]

Questions;

1. Why is the queue empty and what can I do to ensure it registers messages?
2. Is it not locking because my code is not writing messages?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Also didn't send message to queue when you did it on local?

Comment: Yes, it did not... and cant just figure out what the issue is.

Comment: @ Bowman Zhu  from my local run it prints `GotIt`. Nothing goes into the queue

Comment: I have post an answer, you can have a try to see whether the problem still happens on your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

**`function.json`**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "msg",
      "queueName": "outqueue",
      "connection": "AzureStorageQueuesConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

**`local.settings.json`**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureStorageQueuesConnectionString":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

**`host.json`**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 1.2.0)"
  }
}
```

**Original Answer:**

I have do a simple test. Below code works fine on my side, you can have a try:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest,msg: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    input_msg = req.params.get('message')
    logging.info(input_msg)
    msg.set(input_msg)
    return func.HttpResponse(
            "This is a test.",
            status_code=200
    )
```

This is the doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=python#example

Send:

[image]

Queue Storage:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I will try and revert

Comment: still nothing gets written

Comment: @wwnde I test the same code of you. I works with no problem. So it should have no problem with your code. Any limit of your storage account? You can also have a check of the configuration settings I updated.

Comment: are there queue settings that maybe I need to check?

Comment: @wwnde If you use connection string you should have totally access to queue. Can you show the structure of your AzureStorageQueuesConnectionString?(No need to show the account key and account)

Comment: `{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureStorageQueuesConnectionString":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=fffff;AccountKey=dddddd;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}`

Comment: @wwnde Any service read this queue? Maybe try to write to another queue instead of outqueue. Your code and connection string is no problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224508/discussion-between-wwnde-and-bowman-zhu).

Comment: Hi @Bowman Zhu, a quick one. it works well on local but once deployed, when I run using the azure url it doesnt work. Are you able to help? I am happy to post another question if you need me to. Please..

Comment: @wwnde Ok, yes you can post another question. I will do a test. Please show the details.:)

Comment: When I go to the function, configuration and copy the url `https://harvestlayerqueuestorage.azurewebsites.net/api/CentroidsUpdateTrigger?message=11111` nothing is logged to the queue while `https://harvestlayerqueuestorage.azurewebsites.net/api/CentroidsUpdateTrigger?message=11111` does. What could be reason?

Comment: Do you set the configuration settings of the connection string? On local it is in local.settings.json. But on portal azure function app don't get environment variable from local.settings.json. This is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u43Yn.png It is the same with the Values section of local.settings.json.

Comment: @wwnde I am sorry, i forget to @ you. You can have a look of my above comment.

Comment: Let me check and revert

Comment: What do I add in the Name, value? sorry, I am so green in azure

Comment: @wwnde May be we can go to the chat room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224608/discussion-between-bowman-zhu-and-wwnde).

Comment: are you able to help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677939/how-can-i-create-a-python-webhook-sender-app