# How can I create a python webhook sender app?

Tags: python, flask, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

This is a follow up question to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65573962/azure-webhooks-python).

I have a data warehouse table exposed via `xxx.com\data` API  endpoint

I have been querying this table using the following code and parsing it into a dataframe as follows;

```
import requests
import json
import http.client
import pandas as pd

url = "xxx.com\data?q=Active%20%3D1%20and%20LATITUDE%20%3D%20%20%220.000000%22%20and%20LONGITUDE%20%3D%20%220.000000%22&pageSize =300"
payload = {}
headers = {'Authorization': access_token}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
j=json.loads(response.text.encode('utf8'))
df = pd.json_normalize(j['DataSet'])
```

The warehouse table gets periodically updated and I am required to create a webhook to be listened to by the following Azure `httptrigger`;

```
import logging
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    d={
    'Date' :['2016-10-30','2016-10-30','2016-11-01','2016-10-30'],
    'Time':['09:58:11', '10:05:34', '10:07:57', '11:15:32'],
    'Transaction':[2,3,1,1]
    }
    df=pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Date','Time','Transaction'])
    output = df.to_csv (index_label="idx", encoding = "utf-8")
 
return func.HttpResponse(output)
```

When run,the httptrigger successfully listens to the following webhooker sender which I have created and am running locally on my disk.

```
    import logging
    import os
    import json
    import pandas as pd

data={'Lat': '0.000000',
   'Long': '0.000000',
   'Status': '1', 'Channel URL':"xxx.com\data"}

webhook_url="http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1"

r=requests.post(webhook_url, headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'}, data =json.dumps(l))
```

My question is;

1. How can I deploy the webhook sender to the cloud as an app so that every time "`xxx.com\data`" is updated with `Lat==0`,`Long=00` and `Status=1`, a message is send to my webhook listener?

The app can either be Azure/Flask/postman or any other python based webhook builder.

Comment: Do you want the webhook sender running continuously(when data in table changed, send request to httptrigger)?

Comment: Yap,  a webhook sender deployed as an app preferably on Azure.  Do not mind if app developed on any other platform provided it is python driven.

Comment: Your question is still very unclear and uses made up terms like "webhooker sender". A webhook is a callback URL that someone calls. One doesn't _"listen"_ to webhooker. Anyway. I'll try to post an answer as it can't fit in this comment box.

Comment: @Kashyap We cant call webhooks url....they are urls to a custom function. This function has a listerner url, polling url, and payload. Otherwise every url will be a webhook, isntit?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach can be to wrap your sender code into a [Timer Trigger Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python) which would poll your `xxx.com\data` at every x seconds (or whatever frequency you decide) and call your webhook (another http triggered function) if there is any change.

```
{
    "name": "mytimer",
    "type": "timerTrigger",
    "direction": "in",
    "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
}
```

```
import datetime
import logging
import os
import json
import pandas as pd

import azure.functions as func


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.warn('The timer is past due!')
 
    # "xxx.com\data" polling in real scenario
    l={'Lat': '0.000000',
          'Long': '0.000000',
          'Status': '1', 
          'Channel URL':"xxx.com\data"}

    webhook_url="{function app base url}/api/HttpTrigger1"

    r=requests.post(webhook_url, headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'}, data =json.dumps(l))

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

At the end of the day, you can deploy both your webhook function (http trigger) and the sender (timer trigger polling) into a [Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/) app.

You can also think of getting rid of the webhook function altogether (to save one intermediate hop) and do your stuffs into the same timer triggered function.

Comment: This is not what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

1. You currently have some polling logic (under `querying this table using the following code`). If you want to move that to "Cloud" then [create a `TimerTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python#example) function, and put all your poller code in it.
2. If you want to leave that poller code untouched, but want to call some code in "cloud" whenever poller detects a change (updated with `Lat==0,Long=00 and Status=1`), then you can create an [HTTPTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python) function and invoke it from poller whenever it detects the change.

---

Confusing part is this: How do you detect this change today? Where is the poller code hosted and how often is it executed?

If data in DB is changing then only ways you can execute "some code" whenever the data changes is:

1. poll the DB periodically, say every 1 minute and if tehre is a change execute "some code" OR
2. some feature of this DB allows you to configure a REST API (HTTP Webhook) that is called by the DB whenever there is a change. Implement a REST API (e.g. as an `HttpTrigger` function) and put that "some code" that you want executed inside it. Now whenever there is a change the DB calls your webhook/REST-API and "some code" is executed.

and the way to read it is to call a REST API (`xxx.com/data?q=...`) then the only ways you can detect

Comment: This does not answe the question. In my question, I have detailed the http trigger is a listener. I have build a code which when I execute it is listened to by the http. I have build webhooks before but were customised in apps. These webhooks have a listener  url, polling url and payload. I believe I am on the right track. All I need is to upload my code as an app service. Example given here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?utm_source=pycon20&utm_medium=web&tabs=cmd&pivots=python-framework-flask

Comment: This post https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-_25tzo8Cw and this post https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQLRPWi2SeA also concur to my approach

Comment: We cant call webhooks url....they are urls to a custom function, otherwise every url will be a webhook, isntit?

Comment: I currently have an arcgis webhook being listened to by the same httptrigger used here. `xx.com/data` is external and I have no control over it. I therefore cant bring it into azure. I can access it with tokens.